# return an array of checkbox within the selected radio group

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular8

I have a select plan page, which displays three plans for choosing with description in a column(see below). Each plan is a radio group that contains a number of checkbox.

On submit I need to return the currently active radio group with the selected array of checkbox.

```
         radio gold    radio silver    radio platinum
         checkbox      checkbox        checkbox
         checkbox      checkbox        checkbox
         checkbox      checkbox        checkbox
         checkbox      checkbox        checkbox
```

Comment: Hey mate, can you provide some code please for us the see what you've done already

Comment: You should share some of your code and ask a question about it. Most people will not just write the necessary code for you...